# MPMoviePlayerController : Player hides Player Controls permenantly only in blow iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller

MPMoviePlayerController Player hides Player Controls permenantly after pressing done button.

I have a Embedded player with moviePlayer.controlStyle =  MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded, and when user tap on full screen mode in moviePlayerDidEnterFullscreen notification i am  making [moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO]; and transform the player video to Landscape mode

```
moviePlayer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(-90));
```

and setting

```
moviePlayer.controlStyle =  MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
```

Then when i tap on done button and in moviePlayBackDidFinish i am transforming the view back to Portrait mode and setting  controlStyle to Embedded. So far its working fine. After that video will be paused and when i tap on play button its start play and player will stay for a while  and hides for permanently. player no longer will be visible after taping on video. i tried to set player control to embedded after a delay. but nothing is working. Please help in this issue.

This issues is only in version below iOS 6

**Code**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayerDidEnterFullscreen:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification
                                           object:nil];


if (mpVideoPlayerController)
{
    [mpVideoPlayerController.moviePlayer pause];
    [mpVideoPlayerController.moviePlayer stop];
}


mpVideoPlayerController = nil;
mpVideoPlayerController = [[VideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL: theURL];


mpVideoPlayerController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = liveStreaming ? MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming : MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown;

if ([mpVideoPlayerController.moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsAirPlay:)]) {
    mpVideoPlayerController.moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay = YES;
}

[[mpVideoPlayerController.moviePlayer view] setFrame:viewInsetRect];
mpVideoPlayerController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
mpVideoPlayerController.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
[viewController.view addSubview: [mpVideoPlayerController.moviePlayer view]];
[mpVideoPlayerController.moviePlayer play];
}


-(void) moviePlayerDidEnterFullscreen :(NSNotification*)notification {
    [mpVideoPlayerController.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    [self performSelector:@selector(setControlStyleFullscreen) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
                         mpVideoPlayerController.moviePlayer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                         mpVideoPlayerController.moviePlayer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(-90));
                         CGRect frame=[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
                         frame.origin.y=-20;
                         mpVideoPlayerController.moviePlayer.view.frame = frame;//CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480.0, 300.0);
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     }];


}

- (void) setControlStyleFullscreen 
         mpVideoPlayerController.moviePlayer.controlStyle =  MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;

- (void) setControlStyleEmbedded 

        mpVideoPlayerController.moviePlayer.controlStyle =  MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;



- moviePlayBackDidFinish:

    NSLog(@"moviePlayBackDidFinish:");

    [self rotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait frameForView:(viewController).videoContentView.frame];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];

    [self performSelector:@selector(setControlStyleEmbedded) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
```

Comment: Share full code of MPmoviecontroller that you use...

Comment: Thanks Vishal, Please check the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is kind of faulty and triggers those `MPMoviePlayerController` bugs.

- superfluous setFullscreen as we are already in fullscreen.
- superfluous setControlStyle as we are already in control style fullscreen

Generally speaking, you should never enforce things on MPMoviePlayerController that are already done.

```
- (void)moviePlayerDidEnterFullscreen :(NSNotification*)notification 
{
    //
    //remove both lines from this notification handler
    //
    [mpVideoPlayerController.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO];
    [self performSelector:@selector(setControlStyleFullscreen) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
    [...]
}
```

You may as well extend your setControlStyleFullscreen / Embedded implementation by checking for the current mode. That may seem weird but it does help a lot.

```
- (void)setControlStyleEmbedded
{
    if (mpVideoPlayerController.moviePlayer.controlStyle != MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded)
    {
        mpVideoPlayerController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
    }
}

- (void)setControlStyleFullscreen
{
    if (mpVideoPlayerController.moviePlayer.controlStyle != MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen)
    {
        mpVideoPlayerController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
    }
}
```